# mvn clean install giving errors on new local machine

Tags: java, spring, maven, mvn-repo

This is quite unexpected, I recently switched to a new machine and while setting up my dev environment, one of my services has been giving this error on running `mvn clean install`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:35 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-21T22:27:09+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.coderplus.maven.plugins:copy-rename-maven-plugin:1.0:copy (copy-file) on project my-service: Execution copy-file of
goal com.coderplus.maven.plugins:copy-rename-maven-plugin:1.0:copy failed: A required class was missing while executing com.coderplus.maven.plugins:copy-renam
e-maven-plugin:1.0:copy: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.coderplus.maven.plugins:copy-rename-maven-plugin:1.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/com/coderplus/maven/plugins/copy-rename-maven-plugin/1.0/copy-rename-maven-plugin-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar

[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner
```

My first guess would be that I have a dependency missing in my project(not sure which one), although it does BUILD SUCCESS on existing machines including the Jenkins instance.

None of the other services I run have an issue like this.

I've verified that the jars mentioned are not corrupt. Tried deleting the whole `.m2` directory and starting again as well.

Are there any other possibilities I might be missing here?

Edit: Adding the `<plugins>` section of my `pom.xml`
I've been recommended using a newer plugin, but this may add help narrow down the issue further:

```
<plugins>
    <!-- Docker Build Plugin START -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- Docker Build Plugin END -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration><addResources>true</addResources></configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I've removed the `<execution>` part from these to save some scrolling.

Comment: `org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner` is part of [`plexus-utils`](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-utils/). Is `Scanner.class` in your `.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar`? Note: v1.5.8 is from 09-Feb-2009(!). The latest is [v3.3.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils). What's your Maven version?

Comment: I'm using maven 3.6.3 (latest). I understand plexus utils jar is pretty old, but the service is pretty old too. It does have Scanner.class

Comment: The given plugin https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.coderplus.maven.plugins/copy-rename-maven-plugin is simply to old to correctly run with Maven 3. cause it was (looks like) implemented for Maven 2. So simply no chance to use it. Apart from that why is such a plugin being used? What is the use case?

Comment: @khmarbaise I ruled that out that possibility because many other people running this service are using the latest maven build. I just tried downgrading to maven 3.5.4 (same as my jenkins build job config that runs everyday).

Comment: Another important thing to mention: The plugin is not directly mentioned in pom, I believe it's a dependency of existing plugin: maven-resources-plugin:2.7.
Use case: It copies the built Dockerfile (inside a sub-project) to the root location and renames it.

Comment: There is not dependency of maven-resources-plugin. The given plugin is configured somewhere in your build or in one parent you might be using ... apart from that you should correctly move the Dockerfile into the root of your project cause it should be located there...that will solve the problem very easily... Furthermore downgrading Maven will not change a thing ... only defining the plugins with their appropriate versions in your pom file...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the much newer [Wagon Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/):

> Use this plugin to view and transfer resources between repositories using Maven Wagon.

with its [`copy`](https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/copy-mojo.html) goal:

> Copy artifacts from one Wagon repository to another Wagon repository.

instead of the old `copy-rename-maven-plugin`.

Don't get confused by *Wagon repository*. There are simply `source`/`target` URLs and `fromDir`/`toDir` directories. [Wagon supports the `file:` protocol](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/).

Re: one of your comments to your question: The [`maven-resources-plugin:2.7`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.7/maven-plugin) has in its POM:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

and no `copy-rename-maven-plugin`, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Gerold ! I'm considering this. Meanwhile, I've also added the `<plugins>` section to question.

Comment: @PrashantVishwakarma  You're welcome! You wrote in one of your comments to the Q: "_The plugin is not directly mentioned in pom_" but now there is `<plugin><groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>1.0</version></plugin>` in your POM excerpt. Replace this with the Wagon plugin.